# Segues and viewDidLoad/viewDidUnload method

Tags: ios, memory-management, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am making simple storyboard application which has 2 UIViewControllers and I am switching between them by using modal segue. Each UIViewController has one UIButton which is used to perform segue to another UIViewController. In viewDidLoad method I animate appearance of that UIButton on each UIViewController. I am using Cross Dissolve Modal segue.

When I press UIButton on 1st UIViewController I navigate to second UIViewController and animation is executed and 2nd UIViewController is shown. After I press UIButton on 2nd UIView Controller, first UIViewController is shown and it's animation is executed. Everything looks fine and viewDidLoad methods are called for each UIViewController when ever I navigate to it. And that's great.

I tried now to change Modal segue type from Cross Dissolve to other two by default offered in XCode Interface Builder. I changed to Cover Vertical, and everything worked just fine, without changes. **But** when I tried **Flip Horizontal Modal segue**, I saw a problem.

When performing Flip Horizontal Modal segue, my UIButton on both UIViewControllers is shown, but **animation isn't executed**. I tried debugging and I am sure that animation commands are being executed, but animation isn't shown.

So that's my first question: **Does anyone know is there any difference between these types of Modal segues which may cause my animation not showing up?**

Other questions are related to basic theory of segues and memory management. When I perform segue and navigate to some UIViewController, viewDidLoad method is called every time. So, does that mean I created new object instance each time viewDidLoad method was executed?

I also notice that **viewDidUnload method is never called**. So, if answer to previous question is affirmative (each viewDidLoad execution creates new object instance), does that mean that my UIViewController object instances are never being unloaded and deleted? Or ARC is doing garbage collection behind the scenes?

If someone could explain how things works with storyboard segues and memory management/object lifecycle and why viewDidUnload method is never being called, I'd be very grateful.

---

**[edit #1: Trying to unload UIViewController after performing modal segue]**

**[update #1: This shouldn't be done, viewDidUnload will be called automatically]**

I am making segue in IBAction attached to UIButton click. I have written this peace of code to perform modal segue.

```
@try
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueToPerform sender:self];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
}
@finally
{
    [self viewDidUnload];
}
```

I have manually called viewDidUnload in @finally block and I have checked weather viewDidUnload is called in runtime and yes - it is called.

Does this mean I managed to unload my UIViewController object I created when navigating to it with modal segue from another UIViewController and remove it from memory?

Is this method regular as a replacement for:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

because this above line returns me to UIViewController from which I navigated to current UIViewController, but that doesn't fit my needs, because I need to perform new segues from current UIViewController to other UIViewControllers (beside returning back to UIViewController from which I navigated to current one)?

---

**[edit #2: Finish]**

At the end I changed implementation model and loaded new UIViews under single UIViewController after I created separate XIB files for those UIViews. I have marked answer from @dasblinkenlight as the right one since it contains lots of useful informations and discussion on that answer gives good answers to some doubts about using modal segues.

Comment: `viewDidUnload` is **NOT** the inverse of `viewDidLoad`. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11238876/22927

Comment: Thanks for the link and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know the answer to the first part of your question, but once you learn the answer to the second part, I am sure that you would go with a different solution anyway.

> `viewDidLoad` method is called every time. So, does that mean I created new object instance each time `viewDidLoad` method was executed?

Absolutely. "Modal" segue causes the new view to obscure the old one completely until the new view is closed. If you go back and forth many times, your code will accumulate a whole "stack" of views underneath the current one.

> I also notice that `viewDidUnload` method is never called. So, if answer to previous question is affirmative (each `viewDidLoad` execution creates new object instance), does that mean that my `UIViewController` object instances are never being unloaded and deleted?

This is correct, all the view controllers that you create are still there, ready for you to close the views on top of it.

> Or ARC is doing garbage collection behind the scenes?

ARC is not a garbage collector, it is a reference counting mechanism with a little automation from the compiler. The objects are still there.

You should change your code to call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in the second controller, rather than using a modal segue that brings you back to the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dasblinkenlight! Some things are now clearer for me. If I dismiss UIViewController to which I have navigated with modal segue, does that mean I will return to UIViewController from which I navigated to that one? In my (more complex) application I have situation where I can navigate with modal segue to certain UIViewController from two different UIViewControllers. When I reach that destination UIViewController, in that controller I have 2 UIButtons which can take me back to any of these 2 UIViewControllers from which I am able to navigate to current UIViewController.

Comment: If I dismiss current UIViewController on some UIButton click, that means I will be returned to UIViewController from which I navigated to current one, right? Is there any way to dismiss current UIViewController when performing any other segue from current to destination UIViewController and if yes, where should I put dismiss statement, since I also need to execute statement which performs new segue?

Comment: PS: I added [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] in UIButton IBAction when navigating from current UIViewController, but it's viewDidUnload method isn't called again.

Comment: I have made edit #1 to my question @dasblinkenlight. If you can comment that implementation, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @uerceg The calls of `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` are not triggered by dismissing the view, they are triggered by low memory warnings. You should not attempt to call these methods manually: these are only notifications sent to your view controller; they do not actually unload the view from the memory.

Comment: I basically have app which looks like this: 1st UIViewController which opens and can only navigate to 2nd UIViewController. 2nd can navigate back to 1st and on 3 other UIViewControllers. Those 3 UIViewControllers can navigate to either 1st or 2nd UIViewController. I have noticed interesting thing. I started Inspector and was looking Active Bytes in Memory Leaks part. When I start application and load 1st UIViewController, 1.5Mb is used. When I navigate to 2nd, 1.55Mb is used. When I navigate to any of these 3 UIViewControllers, 1.65Mb is used, but when I get back from any ..

Comment: .. of those 3, consumption is back to 1.55Mb. But, when I am switching between 1st and 2nd UIViewController constantly, with each transition, memory consumption is increased by 0.05-0.10Mb. But when I navigate between 2nd and one of those 3 UIViewControllers, memory consumption is constant (rises when navigating to any of those 3, and decreasing when navigating back to 2nd). It looks like some deallocations are being made after all? And yes, this happens without dismissing UIViewController like you advised, but only with performing new modal segues.

Comment: @uerceg I do not know why the memory use does not grow much, but you can easily test if the modal chain remains live by adding a button to each of your views with this handler: `if (self.parentViewController) [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Now navigate around, opening views modally, and then click this button to see if it lets you trace the chain backwards. I think it should.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I added 2 dummy buttons and attached IBAction with this code you wrote. I went from 1st to 2nd UIViewController via button which does modal segue. When I now pushed dummy button on 2nd UIViewController, nothing happened. Same thing when navigating from 2nd to 1st and trying to get back to 2nd with dummy button on 1st UIViewController. if statement fails and no dismiss statement is executed.

Comment: @uerceg This is very strange. I was under the impression that modal segue took care of setting up `parentViewController`, but perhaps I'm wrong. Could you try the same code without the `if`?

Comment: Yes, without if statement it navigates back. I made this test: I went from 1st to 2nd UIViewController and back 5 times by using modal segue. After that I was able to exactly 5 times navigate back by using dummy buttons (probably until I dismissed each UIViewController objects with this dismiss statement). So that means that this dismiss statement removed each newly created object I made with modal segue transition? If yes, that's great, but I still have problem because I don't always navigate BACK to previous UIViewController, but I need to do modal segues to another UIViewControllers.

Comment: @uerceg That's a good news. See if you can call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]` in the `prepareForSegue` to get rid of the *current* view controller before opening the new one. If you can, you'll achieve an effect of a "replacement" segue.

Comment: Okay, I added overridden prepareForSegue method with [self dismissMidalViewControllerAnimated:NO] statement to code which contained these previous two dummy buttons. When I navigated from 1st UIViewController to 2nd I was able to go back with dummy button to 1st one. But when I perform this navigation test: 1st - 2nd - 1st with modal segues and I am currently on 1st UIViewController I am NOT able to get back to 2nd UIViewController like before. Looks like 2nd UIViewController was removed from chain. I don't know why I can navigate from 2nd one to 1st at any time...

Comment: ... (maybe because 1st one is root UIViewController?). I don't have at the moment code version which has functional remaining 3 UIViewControllers so I will be able to check full navigation in several hours. I am really curious what will dummy buttons on those 3 UIViewControllers give as a result. So far seems like this did the trick (with this doubt why am I able to navigate from 2nd to 1st at any time), but I will share my results with remaining UIViewControllers in several hours.

Comment: @uerceg The first view controller is definitely special, because it is the root view controller. That's why I tried adding that `if(self.parentViewController)` to check for situations when it's root, but it did not work. You can try adding a fake view controller as your root, with the sole purpose of displaying your "real" first view controller, and staying in the background after that. Once you implement this, the rest of your navigation should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It is not cleanest solution, but it will fit for my needs. Only one time I will made transition from fake to real 1st UIViewController without performing back transition during app runtime. Another question - this speciality of root UIViewController still causes 1st UIViewController object to be created each time I navigate to it? If yes, I will definitely perform this workaround with fake 1st UIViewController.

Comment: @uerceg I think with a fake view controller your first view controller will no longer be "special": it will follow the same exact lifecycle as the rest of the view controllers in your application, behaving precisely like the the second and the third ones do. Give it a try - it shouldn't be too much coding. I have never tried this trick, but I think it should work.

Comment: Huh, definitely not working as we expected @dasblinkenlight. I navigate from 1st to 2nd UIViewController and everything's fine. 1st probably try to dismiss, but since it's "special", it probably won't. Now I try to navigate from 2nd to 3rd with modal segue, but here's what happens: performSegueWithIdentifier:sender method is executed and right segue is performed, BUT! Instead of navigating to 3rd UIViewController, I am taken back to 1st without any animation. So, dismiss without animation took me back to UIViewController from which I came to 2nd (and that's 1st one)...

Comment: ... Looks like this approach doesn't work. Although performSegueWithIdentifier:sender is executed BEFORE [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO], app doesn't navigate to 3rd UIViewController, but dismisses to 1st one. Really strange.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i have exactly the same problem  is their any new solutions

Comment: @uerceg i have exactly the same problem did you find solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue where I had a complex VC navigation web, and the resulting use of segues (no UINavigationController) was sucking up too much memory.
You may want to take a look at this question/answer to see my final solution.
The conversation here between uerceg and dasblinkenlight helped me in finding this solution.

[Segues and clearing historical ViewControllers from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109388/segues-and-clearing-historical-viewcontrollers-from-memory/14116040#14116040)