# How to come back to Tabbar controller after presenting few modal view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, homescreen

Here is my view hierarchy

Login ————> Dashboard(Tabbar controller with 3 VC's).
From one V.C of tabbar controller Presented 4 VC's one after the other modally.

————> V.C.1————>V.C.2————>V.C.3————>V.C.4.

1.How to go back to tabbar controller from VC4?

2.My app crashes some times due to memory. As i don’t have any back button in all view controllers, i want to remove V.C.1 from memory while presenting V.C.2 and  V.C.2 while presenting VC3 etc .. what is the best way to achieve this ?

3.I have a logout button in one of my view controllers in tabbar,What is the best way to present log in screen? (Currently i was conected segue to login.Is this the correct way?)

Thank you..

Comment: If you want to remove modally presented view controller, you should call `dismiss` method. More about it: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: But VC2 should presented by VC1.after presenting I don't want VC1 to be in memory

Comment: You should read the link that I posted. In general you should remove VC's from the "top". The last one presented should be the first one dismissed (last in first out).